# Troubleshoot code error for If then else Logical VBScript in ArcMap 10.3.1

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, field-calculator, vbscript

I realize this question has been asked in its basic form before, but I've tried a lot of code samples on answers posed to similar questions on this site to no avail.

I'd like to create a new field in my attribute table (Label) that uses the VBScript comparison operators in Field Calculator to define the value based on text values of a field within the table (STATUS).

If the field "STATUS" is "USFS", I want "Label" to equal "USFS".

If the field "STATUS" is not "USFS", I want the "Label" to equal "Other".

However, I always get a return value of "Other".  Here is the pre-logic script code I'm using:

```vbs
dim n

if [STATUS] = USFS Then

n = "USFS"

elseif [STATUS] <> USFS Then

n = "Other"

end if
```

See screenshots.

[image: Attribute Table]  [image: Field Calculator]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While in your description you put quotes around USFS, you don't in your actual code

> If the field "STATUS" is "USFS", I want "Label" to equal "USFS".
>
> If the field "STATUS" is not "USFS", I want the "Label" to equal
>   "Other".

USFS should be in double-quotes.  The `elseif` fires every time because nothing equals USFS (without quotes) which is why they all return a value of "Other".

```vbs
dim n
if [STATUS] = "USFS" Then
n = "USFS"
elseif [STATUS] <> "USFS" Then
n = "Other"
end if
```

Comment: You could make it simpler by setting all to "USFS" and then just check [STATUS] in an if statement. Or, use an else instead of elseif.